# Как перекодировать массив в Node.JS из CP1251 в UTF8?

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, cp1251

Есть массив (точнее объект), как изменить кодировку его элементов из CP1251 в UTF8?

Comment: О каких конкретно элементах речь? Покажите пример. Строки в node.js всегда юникодные и к ним неприменимо понятие кодировки

Comment: @andreymal если совсем конкретно, то для русскоязычных каналов приходит ответ из telegram (core api) в виде массива в кодировке cp1251. его надо сконвертировать в utf8 и отправить в качестве ответа сервера: res.end(JSON.stringify(info));

Comment: @andreymal с англоязычными каналами таких проблем нет, там все приходит в utf8

Comment: "Совсем конкретно" - это код, который продемонстрирует проблемный объект. А по таким мутным словесным описаниям ничего не понятно

Comment: (особенно непонятно, почему библиотека, работающая с telegram, не разбирается с кодировками самостоятельно)

Comment: попробуйте данную библиотеку https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite

Answer (score 2):

Есть 2 способа сделать это.

#### Стандартный

API node.js включает в себя стандартный способ работы с кодировками.

```
const { TextDecoder } = require('util');
const textCP1251 = 'РџСЂРёРІРµС‚, РњРёСЂ'; // Привет, Мир в cp1251
const decoder = new TextDecoder('cp1251');    

console.log(decoder.decode(textCP1251));
```

Однако проблема в том, что для этого способа требуется библиотека icu, собранная со всеми кодировками. В дефолтной поставке nodejs она идёт с ограниченным набором кодировок и cp1251 в этот набор не входит.

#### Библиотека iconv-lite

Есть хорошая библиотека `iconv-lite`, написанная нашим соотечественником. Она на чистом js позволяет работать с огромным числом кодировок.

```
const iconv = require('iconv-lite');
const textCP1251 = 'РџСЂРёРІРµС‚, РњРёСЂ'; // Привет, Мир в cp1251

console.log(iconv.encode(textCP1251, 'cp1251').toString()); // Привет, Мир в utf8
```